# Cannot resolve attribute 'creationPolicy' for component type HGroup

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I'm receiving the following error when trying to set the creation policy for an HGroup:

```
Cannot resolve attribute 'creationPolicy' for component type HGroup
```

It's been a long day but I'm pretty sure there was a property to specify that a component is created immediately in Flex 4 and I thought it was the `creationPolicy` property.

Answer (score 0):

It's been renamed to `itemCreationPolicy` and it accepts the values `immediate` and `deferred`.

[Create and apply view states](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ffa.html)